# After user selects an option of the drop box make text appear on screen

Tags: html

I have a HTML form, which contains a drop box of choises;

```
<select name="Small" type="text">
<option value="default">Select Size</option>
<option value="Small"><?php echo ($Small== 'Small') ? ' selected="selected"' : '';    ?>Small</option>
<option value="Medium"><?php echo ($Small== 'Medium') ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>Medium</option>
<option value="Large">Large</option>
<option value="XLarge">XLarge</option>
</select>
```

I want a text, like price appear on the page after the user chooses one of the drop box options, how can I manage that?

Comment: You'll probably want JavaScript for that.

Comment: You close your opening `option` tag before concatenating your `selected` attribute.

Comment: Learn about event handling in javascript: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use jQuery:

```
$('select[name="Small"]').change(function(){
    $('span').text($(this).val());
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FfJ25/

Comment: They don't NEED to use JQuery. Vanilla javascript would work just fine.

Comment: I've never worked with jQueries, it sounds like I should learn about them. Where should i place that jQuery code snippet in my php script that obtains the drop box, and how can I make a text display $7.99 when the user selects Small